# How to construct a Cayley Table?

Tags: group-theory, cayley-graphs, cayley-table

I have a set G = {e,a,b,c,d,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p} which forms a group, (G, *) which is shown in the Cayley Digraph below.

How do I go about constructing a Cayley table of (G,*), assuming e is the identity.

[image]

All I have so far is:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&e&a& b&c&d&f&g&h&i&j&k&l&m&n&o & p \\ \hline
 a& & &\\ \hline
 b&  & &\\ \hline
 c& c&j&g&f&n&k&i&b&h&p&e&m&d&l&a&o\\ \hline
 d& d&b&a&n&e&l&j&o&p&g&m&f&k&c&h&i \\ \hline
 f&  & &\\ \hline
 g&  & &\\ \hline
 h&  & &\\ \hline
 i& i&l&f&g&p&b&c&k&e&n&h&a&o&j&m&d\\ \hline
 j&  & &\\ \hline
 k&  & &\\ \hline
 l&  & &\\ \hline
 m&  & &\\ \hline
 n&  & &\\ \hline
 o&  & &\\ \hline
 p&  & &\\ 
\end{array}

I don't think this is correct & have completely confused myself, any help and support would be much appreciated.

Comment: The first column and first row are always the easiest in a Cayley Table. Fill those in and see where you can get from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good so far....
Try k next.  Follow the same rule as c but follow the arrows backwards.

And f = c^2, takes everything across the black diamonds.
P takes everything across the red/blue squares.
Then it starts getting trickier.

n = dc, na = d(ca) = dj = g.

Comment: Thank you, think i got it!